# Like Button Error - I must setup the Connect Base Domains for my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, app-id

I've implemented a Facebook Like button on this page: http://gointrigue.com/sandbox/2011/08/hello-world/

Unfortunately it's giving me an error. It tells me

```
"The app ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag is not allowed on this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your app to be a prefix of http://gointrigue.com/sandbox/2011/08/hello-world/."
```

I've already done this. Though in my App Settings, the field I am editing is called "App Domain" and not "Connect Base Domains". My Wordpress site is located at gointrigue.com/sandbox and my App Settings in Facebook has the App Domain set to "gointrigue.com".

What am I doing wrong?